# How to call ajax modalpop with dynamically created buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I'm dynamically creating buttons with values from a database, and I have a modalpopup using ajax. I know that when using the popup I have to set a targetid, that's fine when its a predefined button. But how do you get the modalpopup to recognize a target when it dynamically created without having to use stringbuilder and rebuild a modalpopup on an eventhandler, and if I'm left to using stringbuilder then how do I call that when its created?
This is the code for the buttons

```
button.ID = Convert.ToString(myID);
button.Text = myStr;
button.PostBackUrl = "~/WebForm2.aspx?SubjectID=" + myID;
button.CssClass = "DynamicButtonOverlay";
```

This is the modalpopup

```
<asp:Panel ID="MyPanel" runat="server" CssClass="myModalPopup">
        <table style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>Select News</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewsToDelete" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteNews" runat="server" Text="Radera" CssClass="btn btn-danger pull-left" OnClick="btnDeleteNews_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" class="btn btn-success pull-right" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</asp:Panel>
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="MyPanel" BackgroundCssClass="myModalBackground" TargetControlID="Submit1" OkControlID="btnClose"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

This is the code generating the buttons..

```
test.GetSubjects();
        int subjectid = 0;

        // Current row count.
        int rowCtr;// = 0;
        // Total number of cells per row (columns).
        int cellCtr;
        // Current cell counter.
        int cellCnt;

        //count number of rows in dataset
        int rN = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

        cellCnt = 4;


        for (rowCtr = 1; rowCtr <= rN; rowCtr++)
        {
            // Create a new row and add it to the table.
            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);

            for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= 4; cellCtr++)
            {
                //
                Button button = new Button();
                //
                HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
                // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();


                /* If the rowcounter is equal to the record numbers
                 * then it has to break because if not it will throw an error
                 * saying that there is no row at ending position */

                if (rowCtr == rN)
                    break;

                string myStr = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr - 1]["SubjectName"].ToString();
                int myID = Convert.ToInt32(test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr - 1]["SubjectID"].ToString());

                button.ID = Convert.ToString(myID);
                button.Text = myStr;
                button.PostBackUrl = "~/WebForm2.aspx?SubjectID=" + myID;
                button.CssClass = "DynamicButtonOverlay";
                tCell.Controls.Add(button);

                tCell.CssClass = "DynamicButtonOverlay";
                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
                rowCtr++;
                /* If the cellcount is 3 then it needs to break, if not then 
                 * you'll miss every 4rth record, don't know why. But this works */

                if (cellCtr == 4)
                {
                    rowCtr = rowCtr - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: you need to render it at oninit first.

Comment: do you have any example?

Comment: maybe you can post some of your script to dynamic generate the buttons. so that i can see the perfect match for you.  by the way, do you mean the buttons you have created , you need to call the same modalpopupextender ?

Comment: no problem i'll make an edit and add it. Yes when the buttons are created they will all call the same modalpopup, the buttons are subjects and when anyone is clicked, the modalpopup is a form to be able to edit the subject. So yes, any button needs to call the same modalpopupextender.

Comment: in that case, you no need so headache to detact each button dynamically point the targetid to the clicked button.  why not, you put at <DIV style="display:none"> <asp:button .... ></DIV> and then, when any of the button click ( you need to +=new event for each new dynamically created buttons). to call the modal popup .show().

Comment: I get what you are saying, i'll give that a try.

Comment: <DIV style="display:none"> <asp:button .... ></DIV>  the button 's id inside is the modalpopup targetid

Comment: I can't get it figured out. The buttons ids are unknown, its the id from the database. I created a button handler event to handle all the buttons click event and have it calling the modalpopupextender1.show(), but I cant target an id for it because the id's are all different. So when I run it, it throws an error saying that there is no valid targetid.

Comment: <DIV style="display:none"> <asp:button .... ></DIV> the button 's id inside is the modalpopup targetid .  the button that inside the hidden div is for the modalpopup static point to that id.   other buttons that dynamically created by you, you just need to call modalpopup.show()

Comment: if you don't mind, please paste your code here with html, then i maybe may help your problem.

Comment: I found a way to do what I wanted by the buttons calling a JavaScript function to open the modalpopup. Now I just need to figure out how to grab the Id from the button that was clicked so I can populate the fields in the popup